# syntax with for loop and list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of 30 items, some have fits and some have just have 0's. 
And I want to plot the fits of all 30 fits. to get the fits I built a list where if it could fit the data it did and if not it put a 0. so the list all the fits (allfit) have some fits with 0's mixed in.

I have code like this:

```
      for ( i in 1:30){

    if (allfit[[i]] != 0)
{

    plot(x,y,type='l')
    par(new=TRUE)
    lines(x,predict(allfit[[i]],col='red'))
}
    else plot(y=0)
```

}

I'm getting list object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.

I know its a syntax problem but I'm not sure where. please help!

Comment: what is `x` and `y` in your plot? can you show dput of `allfit`?

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in `plot(...`

Comment: sorry that was a typo!

Comment: x and y are just time vs Current amplitude. I simplified it because I don't think those are the problems. if i set i =1 it works and if i set it i=4 (which is one of the fits with a 0) it doesn't work so i think it has to do with how i'm calling allfit

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to instead of using if (allfit[[i]] !=0) to use (!is.numeric(allfit[[i]]).